# CSS: Border on top of navigation item when hovering

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

Here is the a screenshot of the mock up:

[image]

This is what I have:

[image]

I am still working on the shadow and the bottom border will be static across the entire width of the container.

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="masthead">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"></a>
    </div>

    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                        <li>How we do it</li>
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>Clients</li>
                        <li>Whats new</li>
                        <li>Contact</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Here is my sass:

```
.masthead {
    padding-top: 10px;

    nav {
        &.collapse {
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0)));
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 10%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 45%);

            text-transform: uppercase;

            ul { padding-top: 10px; }
            ul > li {
                margin: 0 20px;
                &:hover { border-top: 3px solid #7ad3f7 }
            }
        }
    }

    .navbar-brand {
        display: block;
        height: 51px;
        width: 209px;
        background: asset-url('logo.png') top left no-repeat;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
}
```

What I am having issues with is trying to get my markup to look like the mockup. How do I get the top border (on-hover) to appear outside the navigation container area?

Comment: So, we have your mock-up, your current result, your SASS and your mark-up. But we don't seem to have a question anywhere.

Comment: @DavidThomas - Fixed it. I hit submit before I finished my thought

Comment: Just add `Position: relative;` and `top: -4px;` to `li` (or your list item)

Comment: @ThePragmatick - Thanks so much!! Now with your changes, the `li` is making the text "jump" up and down when I hover over the navigation. Anyway to get the text to not jump when I hover over a nav item?

Comment: Add white border to normal `li`, i mean when its not in hover state/

Comment: @ThePragmatick - Can you answer this question with your comment? Your suggestions works great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with border and positioning.

Add a transparent border to the regular `li` element (unhovered).
Change the color to `#7ad3f7` for hover. Also add `position: relative;` and `top: -15px;` to position the border correctly.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pydLdcuf/3/)**

CSS:

```
.masthead nav.collapse ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 6px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    height: 51px;
    line-height: 51px;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
}
.masthead nav.collapse ul > li:hover {
    border-top: 6px solid #7ad3f7;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach using a `:before` pseudo element:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/g93r691u/show/)

```
.masthead nav.collapse ul {
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.masthead nav.collapse ul > li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background: #7ad3f7;
    height: 4px;
    top: -14px;
    display: none;
}
.masthead nav.collapse ul > li:hover:before {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: When I load up the jsfiddle the `result` is blank

Comment: @dennismonsewicz Resize the window. The navbar is hidden due to the conditional media queries used by bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks so much for this example! Learn something new every day

Answer (score 0):

This example is using the `:after` pseudo selector. I've also included a simple animation on the hover effect. This is because rather than using a border, which makes this design a lot harder, I've chosen to use the pseudo class instead.

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 45%);
}
li:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: transparent;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
li:hover:after {
  background: #7ad3f7;
  left: 0;
  top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
</ul>
```